# "Unable to initialize command context" while deploying war to JBoss using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, deployment, jboss, wildfly, devops

I created maven project in Jenkins and it has a step to deploy war to JBoss using `Wildfy Deployer Plugin` with following details -

1. WAR/EAR files   = ./target/test.war
2. Hostname = localhost
3. Port - 8181

But I run job it results into following error -

```
2019-10-14 13:42:48.720+0000 [id=185]   INFO    hudson.model.Run#execute: deploy-war-to-jboss #4 main build action completed: FAILURE
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to initialize command context.
    at org.jboss.as.cli.scriptsupport.CLI.connect(CLI.java:152)
    at org.jboss.as.cli.scriptsupport.CLI.connect(CLI.java:135)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.wildfly.WildflyBuilder.perform(WildflyBuilder.java:136)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:741)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:206)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1815)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Caused by: org.jboss.as.cli.CliInitializationException: Failed to load org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CommandContextFactoryImpl
    at org.jboss.as.cli.CommandContextFactory.getInstance(CommandContextFactory.java:41)
    at org.jboss.as.cli.scriptsupport.CLI.connect(CLI.java:149)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CommandContextFactoryImpl
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:555)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.as.cli.CommandContextFactory.getInstance(CommandContextFactory.java:39)
    ... 12 more
2019-10-14 13:44:06.945+0000 [id=230]   INFO    hudson.model.Run#execute: deploy-war-to-jboss #5 main build action completed: FAILURE
```

Please help to understand what's wrong here.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the plugin, but it can't seem to find the implementation class for CLI. You'll want to make sure it's on the class path.

Comment: Try to deploy directly on Wildfly/EAP then if the error occur again we can take a look.